# VB Script adds blank line every time it is run

Tags: vbscript

I don't do much vb scripting. Here's a script that I acquired to replace a string. The problem with it is that it adds an extra blank line every time it is run. I call it from a bat file with:
CSCRIPT replace.vbs "FolderName\FileName.ext" "TextToChange" "NewText" 
What do I need to change to prevent that?
Thanks :)

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

strFileName = Wscript.Arguments(0)
strOldText = Wscript.Arguments(1)
strNewText = Wscript.Arguments(2)

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strNewText = Replace(strText, strOldText, strNewText)

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFileName, ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strNewText
objFile.Close
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`objFile.ReadAll` slurps the whole file, including the terminating EOL(s). `objFile.WriteLine strNewText` writes that string **and** an EOL back. So use `objFile.Write strNewText` instead.

Comment: Great! That fixed it. Thanks much.